# How to Pass an Array of Struct to Class in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, struct

All, I am having difficulty passing a `struct` to a class constructor. I am in the process of multi-threading a part of an existing code. In one class the following structure is defined:

```
SchemaFileRec[] m_TableList;

struct SchemaFileRec
{
    public ArrayList  saFile;
    public ArrayList  saImpTab;
    public ArrayList  saSheet;
    // And others...
    public int[]      nColHead;
    public int[]      nSkipBeg;
    public int[]      nSkipEnd;
    public string     strADTFld;
};
```

This is used in a method (old method called `ExecCmd`) to do some processing. I am re-writing this method to a class; in fact a subclass of `BackgroundWorker`. Essentally I am taking a method that deals with some "long-running" task, and multi-thredding it. I have:

```
public class ExecCmdsThredded : BackgroundWorker 
{
    // Global variables and constants.
    private int nTable;
    private List<int> kPrmArray = null;
    private List<object> StructureArray = null;
    private SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet worksheet;

    // Default constructor to handle thred properties.
    public ExecCmdsThredded()
    {
        WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    // Constructor to parse relevant parameters to worker.
    // Or as an array of objects public ExecCmdsThredded(object[] _StructArr, etc. 
    public ExecCmdsThredded(List<object> _StructArr, List<int> _kPrmArr, ArrayList[] _saCmd, 
                            int _nTable, SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet _worksheet) : this()
    {
        this.nTable = _nTable;
        this.kPrmArray = _kPrmArr;
        this.StructureArray = _StructArr;
        this.worksheet = _worksheet;
    } 
    // ...
```

I now want to pass the structure from above to `ExecCmdsThredded` class via the constructor but I have never had to do this before and I am not sure if it is possible the way I want to do it? I could explicitly pass every componant of the `struct` but I want to avoid this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You mean "pass to" instead of "parse to", are you asking how to pass an array of structs to a class constructor like `public ExecCmdsThredded(SchemaFileRec[] schemaFileRecs)` ?

Comment: I do mean 'pass' apologies (it has not been a good day). Yes this is what I want to do. But I want to pass many different `structs` as one object array as what is passed to the class may change, so it has to be a generic container in the constructor.

Comment: You can always pass an array of objects `object[]` and inside you can box any type of struct or class, it is not advised because of the boxing/unboxing side effects. Example of what I mean: `new ExecCmdsThredded(new object[] { new SchemaFileRec(), new AnotherSchema() });` But I recommend dropping the structs, create classes so that you can use Generics instead, makes the code more readable at least.

Comment: That is very helpful. In fact, I am happy to accept this as the answer if you propose it as one.

Comment: Maybe you can upvote it then since you already accepted another answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel uncomfortable whenever I start passing structs. When you have a collection of structs that you want to pass as a parameter, carefully revisit the design ..."why am I using a struct?" I recommend converting the struct to a class in **most** cases.

There are several links to help you decide on whether to use a struct or class. Search through [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=when%20to%20use%20struct%20or%20class) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

Comment: That is helpful. I am relatively new to C# an indeed commercial programming. I have been given this old and complex (non-commented) code and want to avoid getting in too deep. But this point has been made twice and I will heed your advice. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Killercam: see my edit adding some useful resource links on structs and classes

Answer (score 2):

You can always pass an array of objects object[] and inside you can box any type of struct or class, it is not advised because of the boxing/unboxing side effects. Example of what I mean:

`new ExecCmdsThredded(new object[] { new SchemaFileRec(), new AnotherSchema() });`

**But I recommend dropping the structs**, create classes so that you can use `Generics` instead, makes the code more readable at least.